# Mongodb Query To select records from multiple key

Tags: mongodb, select

Let the records in the database be

```
{"_id":"1","unit":"a1", "vehicle1" : "car"}
{"_id":"2","unit":"a2", "vehicle1" : "truck", "vehicle2" : "bike"}
{"_id":"3","unit":"b1", "vehicle1" : "car"}
{"_id":"4","unit":"zz", "vehicle1" : "truck", "vehicle2" : "car", "vehicle3" : "car" }
```

Is there a command that will find an entry or all the entries with the following arguments:

```
db.accidents.find( { vehicle*: "bike" } );
```

Comment: No, there isn't; and that's a good indication that your schema is flawed.  It would be much cleaner to switch to a single `vehicle` array like Sushant suggests in his answer.

Comment: For more info on indexing arrays, see [multikey indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#index-type-multikey) in the MongoDB documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead have a array for vehicles.

Here is a sample JSON which you can insert

```
{"_id":"2", "unit":"a2", "vehicle": ["truck", "bike"]}
```

And the way you can query is:

```
db.accidents.find({"vehicle":"bike"});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't want to alter your data, this is the only way I can think of.

```
db.accidents.find( { $or: [
  {"vehicle1": "bike"}, 
  {"vehicle2": "bike"}, 
  {"vehicle2": "bike"}
]} )
```

Requires obviously that you know how many vehicle* variants there are. Arrays as Sushant proposes would be much nicer.

Comment: You are brilliant, after hours of search, plus one from me!
`db.Selfie.find( { $and: [ { _id: 0.0}, {"kEN8rMiSvqeiSFw8n9ZgTYbqzXf1":{'$exists': 1}} ] } );`

Answer (score 0):

And if vehicle number is important to you.

```
{"_id": "2", 
 "unit": "a2",
 "vehicle": [{no: 1, name: "truck"}, {no:2, name: "bike"}]
}
```

After that you can query on each field alone as well as make use of advance query operations.

Comment: i come back after almost 1 year, i've forgot my login. thanks Sushant and everyone. indeed, my schema was wrong.